# Can't find "Edit Profile & Settings" to delete my account?

Tags: discussion

I read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account link yet I can't find the edit profile and settings, not to mention delete profile option. Has the process or the place where the option is located changed?

Answer (score 2):

And now I found it under Stack Overflow. When I was trying to access it via the meta exchange it totally was not obvious. To me at least. Sigh.

Comment: You're not alone. It's not obvious.